# Removing *ngIf breaks, hardcoding "true" works

Tags: angular

I have some fairly simple code here:

```
<abc-richtexteditor
 matInput
 placeholder="Content"
 id="{{ (subsection.id) + '-editor' }}"
 required
 [canEdit]="canEditFeature"
 [initialValue]="subsection.content">
</abc-richtexteditor>
```

That above breaks the code in the component `<abc-richtexteditor>` but if I just hard code `true` inside `*ngIf` then it works fine.

```
<abc-richtexteditor
 *ngIf="true"
 matInput
 placeholder="Content"
 id="{{ (subsection.id) + '-editor' }}"
 required
 [canEdit]="canEditFeature"
 [initialValue]="subsection.content">
</abc-richtexteditor>
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContent' of undefined
    at RichtexteditorComponent.get
```

related to:

```
get value (): string {
    return this.editor.getContent();
}
```

related to:

```
<editor
 test="test"
 name="editor"
 apiKey="test"
 [initialValue]="initialValue"
 [init]="config">
</editor>
```

related to:

```
get config() {
    return  {
        ...
        setup: (editor) => {
            this.editor = editor;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the error if you dont put the ngIf ?

Comment: It just messes up some code down the line, but I think its related to `[initialValue]` getting passed in as `undefined`.

Comment: Try doing this `[initialValue]="subsection?.content || ''"` where you assign the value or an empty string.

Comment: @theblindprophet post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. At the very least post the exact and complete error you get. Saying "it breaks" or "I think it's related to blabla" desn't allow us to give any help.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: Added the error and most of the code related.

Comment: Maybe just protecting for the error in the `value` getter would work: `return this.editor ? this.editor.getContent() : null;`. It could be that using `ngIf` causes the display of the element to be delayed, and gives the opportunity for `this.editor` to be defined before it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to describe angular component life cycle (OnInit, AfterViewInit).
Imagine you have three components. A, B, C.

Inside the `A` component template you have the following:

`<B [someInput]="valueFromAComponent"></B>`

And inside your `B` component template:

`<C [someInput]="valueFromBComponent"></C>`

Your components cycle will be the following:

1. Component `A` constructor.
2. Component `B` constructor.
3. Component `C` constructor.
4. Component `A` ngOnInit.
5. Component `B` ngOnInit.
6. Component `C` ngOnInit.
7. Component `C` ngAfterViewInit.
8. Component `B` ngAfterViewInit.
9. Component `A` ngAfterViewInit.

On `ngOnInit` all the input value will be passed so based on that you should use `ngIf` in your child component till your parent component set the input value.

If you put any value not initialized, Angular change detection will run inside your `C` component and throw an exception like `cannot read property x of undefined`.

So if your child component depends on some input from your parent component you should use `ngIf` till the value has the right value.

I hope this will help you to solve your issue :).

Answer (score 0):

It’s working with ngif because angular doesn’t create a view with ngif until everything is init and the value is true.

So it looks like your content value is undefined when your html renders.

Can you please post the code how are you setting the subsection.value

Just move ur config() code to onInit() inside your conponent class